# Cannot get the substring of a String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, substring, undefined

I am trying to get the substring from a variable when the content length is longer than 120 chars.

```
$.ajax({
          url: url,
          dataType: 'json',
          async: false,
          success: function(data){
              $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                      var name = item.name;
                      var itemId = item.itemId;

                    if(name.length >= 120) {
                        selectHTML += '<option value=' + itemId + '>' + name.substr(0, 120) + '</option>';
                      } else {
                      selectHTML += '<option value=' + itemId + '>' + name + '</option>';
                    }
            });
          }
    });
```

But as a result, I always get this:

```
name is undefined
```

When I do it without `substring()`, it works without problems. Any suggestions?

---

**Edit:**
Error is thrown on this line:

```
if(name.length >= 120) {
```

Comment: Please show us some real code. The code you posted works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/3M7Gc/

Comment: Here you go, my whole ajax function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `if (name.length >= 120)` to `if (name && name.length >= 120)`

Comment: could you please explain the reason ?

Comment: `name` (i.e. `item.name`) may be `undefined`, so it has to be included in the check. Ofcourse I can't explain _why_ `name` may be `undefined`, because I don't know the data behind it.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that one of the `item`s does not contain a `name`.

Use `console.log(data)` to figure out what you actually receive - nothing is wrong with your JavaScript code.

If you cannot change the server-side code, you could fallback to an empty name:

```
var name = item.name || '';
```